# How do I make a downloaded file automatically insert into a spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, download, automation

Forgive me if this is an amateur question or is out right impossible. I am new to coding. Here is my scenario...

I frequently download research reports that I find myself having to refer back to constantly months/ years later. So, what I have done is inputted all of the past reports I have read into a spreadsheet with columns titling "Title", "Date", "Analyst". What I would like to do is be able to automatically download new research reports to the my default folder and have them automatically insert as the file name with a hyperlink in the "Title" column. I operate the spreadsheet using google sheets because it is shared between multiple people if that makes a difference.

I would really appreciate any help. I have done some basic html and javascript coding, and I have a feeling this is definitely going to be a little more advanced.

Comment: Which version of Excel do you use? Do you have power query installed? If yes then its very easy.

Comment: You're going to get downgraded, please add the operating system and explain exactly what you need with maybe a little example table. There are a few command line tools that can probably accomplish what you need, wget or curl for the download, if using Excel then MS has some good tools, otherwise a short Java program using POI would be my go to.